# How can I concat an array of integer in MongoDB aggregation method?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a field in mongodb document which is an array of integer as like:

> `import_ids=[5200, 4710, 100]`

I want this array as double ## separated string, So that expected result would be

```
import_hashed="5200##4710##100"
```

I have tried with following code in $project pipeline of aggregation method.

```
 {
     $projct:{
      import_hashed:{
           $reduce:{
              input:"$import_ids",
              initialValue:"",
              in:{$concat:["$$value", "##", "$$this"]}
             }
         }
      } 
 }
```

But no result found and no erros too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

You can use [**`$toLower`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLower/) aggregation to convert integer to string or [**`$toString`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/) if you are using mongodb **4.0**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "import_hashed": {
      "$let": {
        "vars": {
          "key": {
            "$reduce": {
              "input": "$import_ids",
              "initialValue": "",
              "in": { "$concat": ["$$value", "##", { "$toLower": "$$this" }] }
            }
          }
        },
        "in": { "$substrCP": ["$$key", 2, { "$strLenCP": "$$key" }] }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Output

```
{ "import_hashed": "5200##4710##100 }
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response its working, But result is not perfect. I am getting following result which are single array integer

import_hashed: "##287"
and from multiple array element
import_hashed: "##5200##4710##100"

I don't expect first hash in the resulted string.